# how to merge two sql results

Tags: mysql

Query 1 :

```
select count(*) as cyclecout , serial number from segment 
where serial number in ('lkg','iip') and weight<>0
 and starttime >= 02/15/2020 and entire <= 05/12/2020 
groupby serialnumber
```

The above query will give output as

```
Cyclecout      serialnumber 
123               lkg
234               iip
```

Query 2 :

```
select count(*) as total , serial number from segment 
where serial number in ('lkg','iip') and weight=560
 and starttime >= 02/15/2020 and entire <= 05/12/2020
 groupby serialnumber
```

This will give output as

```
Total              serialnumber 
111                  lkg 
123                  iip
```

Now I want a SQL query which will merge the two results and provide output as

```
Cyclecout  total   serialnumber 
123         111      lkg 
234         123      iip
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Merge Query :

```
select count(*) as cyclecout,se.total , serial number from segment st
Inner Join 
(select count(*) as total , serial number from segment 
where serial number in ('lkg','iip') and weight=560
 and starttime >= 02/15/2020 and entire <= 05/12/2020
 groupby serialnumber ) se
on st.serial number=se.serial number
where serial number in ('lkg','iip') and weight<>0
 and starttime >= 02/15/2020 and entire <= 05/12/2020 
groupby serialnumber
```